# Timage1 and Timage2 inside Timage3

Tags: delphi, image

hi is it possible to insert  Timage1 and Timage2 inside Timage3.
 if my Timage1 is 100x100 and my Timage2 100x100 then they will be side by side inside 200x100 in Timage3 is it possible to do so?

thank you

Answer (score 7):

Essentially, you are asking if you can create a bitmap bm3 which consists of two given bitmaps, bm1 and bm2, side by side. This is easy, but the exact implementation depends on your specific context. But in principle, you could do

```
bm3 := TBitmap.Create;
bm3.SetSize(200, 100);
BitBlt(bm3.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, 100, 100, bm1.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
BitBlt(bm3.Canvas.Handle, 100, 0, 100, 100, bm2.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

if bm1 and bm2 are both 100×100 sq. px. TBitmap objects.

Alternatively, if you prefer to work with VCL rather than Windows GDI, you can replace the two BitBlt lines with

```
bm3.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, bm1);
bm3.Canvas.Draw(100, 0, bm2);
```

A complete example:

```
var
  bm1, bm2, bm3: TBitmap;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

  // Load bm1 and bm2
  bm1 := TBitmap.Create;
  bm1.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Desktop\red.bmp');
  bm2 := TBitmap.Create;
  bm2.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Desktop\blue.bmp');

  bm3 := TBitmap.Create;
  bm3.SetSize(200, 100);
  bm3.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, bm1);
  bm3.Canvas.Draw(100, 0, bm2);

end;

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Canvas.Draw(0, 0, bm3);
end;
```

## In Case of TImage Components

Assume that you have three TImage controls on your form, Image1, Image2, and Image3, and that the two first have pictures in them. Then you can do

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  tmp: TBitmap;
begin

  tmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    tmp.SetSize(Image1.Picture.Width + Image2.Picture.Width, max(Image1.Picture.Height, Image2.Picture.Height));
    tmp.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, bm1);
    tmp.Canvas.Draw(Image1.Picture.Width, 0, bm2);
    Image3.Picture.Assign(tmp);
  finally
    tmp.Free;
  end;

end;
```

to let Image3 display the pictures of Image1 and Image2 side by side.

Comment: yes the basic is that . i add the 2 image inside a 3 one . but realy i wouth only nead to print the image 3 and then free . like if i select image 1+2. thank´s